# How can I make a Custom Image picker reusable component with image preview in react-native?

Tags: react-native

I want to make a resuable DocumentPicker component where a user can add a front side and backside of document. When the user adds image I also want to show uploaded image preview. Can I make a resuable componet so that I dont have to make two different component for the same usecase. Can anybody show me example using expo-image-picker.

Comment: pass the result to https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-gallery

Comment: Sorry you didnt get it what I was trying to say